# Use a function for each of the ways you're printing out things?

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers

Rewrite this program to use a function for each of the ways you're printing out things. Try to pass pointers to these functions so they work on the data. Remember you can declare a function to accept a pointer, but just use it like an array.

How do you do? I have c code which are with for looping printing out index array and pointer index. Here right code without function:

```
       int main(int argc, char * argv[])
       {

       int number[] = {123, 456, 789};
       char *strchars[] = {
         "ABC", "DEF", "GHI"
       };

       int count = sizeof(number) / sizeof(int);
       int i = 0;

       for(i = 0; i < count; i++) {
          printf("%s has %d \n", strchars[i], number[i]);
       }

       // with pointers

       int *po_number = number;
       char **po_strchars = strchars;

       // loop with pointiers

       for(i = 0; i < count; i++) {
           printf("%s has %d \n", *(po_strchars+i), *(po_number+i));
       }
       return 0;
    }
```

But i need use for each of the ways printing out things. But I can't figure out. Here my code with functions but without pointer and chars only integer. Give me how to make it right:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    // void print_arg(int a[], int b[]);

    // now it right?

    // void print_arg(int a[], int b[])

    void print_arg(int a, int b);

    // or now it right?

    void print_arg(int a, int b)
    {
          int a;
          int b;
          int count = sizeof(a) / sizeof(int);
          int i = 0;
              //and it
          for(i = 0; i < count; i++) {
              printf("%d and %d\n", a[i], b[i]);
          }
    } 

    int main(void)
    {
          int number[] = {22, 32, 22, 82, 2};
          int strchars[] = {12, 12, 12, 12, 12};

          int count = sizeof(number) / sizeof(int);
          print_arg(number[], strchars[]);

          return 0;
    }
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking, but note that `sizeof` returns the compile-time size of a type; for a function parameter `int a[]` that will be the size of an `(int *)`, not the runtime size of the presumed array passed to it.  You've also shadowed the function parameters in your example, and it's not clear what you were trying to accomplish with that.

Comment: This code is oh-so-wrong in so many different ways.  Sorry :(  For example, passing "int a[]" as a parameter and then declaring "int a[]" as a parameter won't work.  If you pass a[] into a function, then "sizeof(a)" won't work (it will always return "4").  Etc

Comment: Q: What exactly do you mean by "each of the ways of printing out things"?

Comment: Rewrite this program to use a function for each of the ways you're printing out things. Try to pass pointers to these functions so they work on the data. Remember you can declare a function to accept a pointer, but just use it like an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you trying to write a function that will print the data?

```
void print_array_args(int a[], int b[], int count)
{
  int i = 0;
  for(i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    printf("%d and %d\n", a[i], b[i]); // You can treat arrays as arrays...
    printf("%d and %d\n", *(a+i), *(b+i)); // ... or as pointers.
  }
} 

void print_pointer_args(int *a, int *b, int count)
{
  int i = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    printf("%d and %d\n", a[i], b[i]);     // You can treat pointers as arrays...
    printf("%d and %d\n", *(a+i), *(b+i)); // ... or as pointers.
  }
} 


int main(void)
{
  int number[] = {22, 32, 22, 82, 2};      // You can declare an array...
  int *strchars = malloc(5 * sizeof(int)); // ... or a pointer

  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    strchars[i] = 12;      // You can initialize as an array....
    *(strchars + i) = 12;  // ... or as a pointer
  }

  int strchars[] = {12, 12, 12, 12, 12};
  int count = sizeof(number) / sizeof(int);
  print_array_args(number, strchars, count);
  print_pointer_args(number, strchars, count);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not I need first right code rewrite with function and pointers too.

Comment: Thanks, my problem was i dont define count how int in function.

Comment: This ok now. Thanks you much. It help me. I can now figure out this closer.

Comment: @Adam Liss - I'm not sure how you figured out what Jager Note was looking for - but you did.  Kudos!

Comment: @paulsm4: Thank you.  As I used to remind my Tech Support lead, before you can debug the problem, sometimes you need to debug the customer.  Clairvoyance is helpful.  ;-)